# What is the equivalent of this EF6 entity relationship in EF Core 7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, .net-7.0

I moved my entities with a `1:0..1` relationship from *EF6* to *EF Core 7* and I want to define their relationships.

Here are my entities (simplified for the question):

```
public class MyEntity 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public virtual MyGroup MyEntityMyGroup{ get; set; }
}

public class MyGroup
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public virtual MyEntity MyEntity{ get; set; }
}
```

My *EF6 DbContext* class has the following configuration inside `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
                .HasRequired(myEntity => myEntity.MyEntityMyGroup)
                .WithOptional(group => group.MyEntity);
```

**What is the equivalent of the configuration above in EF Core 7?**
(I do not have a nullable foreign key on the `MyGroup` entity.)

Comment: If you don't have a nullable FK in `MyGroup` then you have an _impossible_ DB design (unless you're using Postgres' Deferred Constraints?) because that means inserting a new `MyGroup` requires an existing `MyEntity` - but any new `MyEntity` cannot be inserted without an existing `MyGroup.Id` value - which is impossible - that's why EF6 makes you use `WithOptional`, because "true" `1:1` relationships are not possible in conventional RDBMSs without deferred-constraints (to my knowledge, that's only Postgres, and maybe Oracle)

Comment: So the solution is to make your `MyEntity`'s FK `NULL`-able which allows you to actually insert data without getting into a logical paradox.... out of curiosity, I'd like to see your deployed DB's `CREATE TABLE` statements (assuming you never defined any of your tables yourself in SQL?) because I'd love to see how EF actually handled this...

Comment: ...or did you use EF to map an existing database to entity-types and also use raw SQL for INSERTs and only use EF for read-only queries which can safely assume that (normally impossible) "`1:1`" relationships are perfectly fine in your use-case? (for example, your C# entity type could actually be a `VIEW`, not a `TABLE` - and with `NOT NULL` FK columns?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF6, the following

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .HasRequired(myEntity => myEntity.MyEntityMyGroup)
    .WithOptional(group => group.MyEntity);
```

means that `MyGroup` is the *principal* and `MyEntity` is the *dependent* with `MyEntity.Id` being both PK and FK (the so called *"Shared Primary Key Association"*).

In EF Core the same is expressed with the following fluent configuration:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .HasOne(myEntity => myEntity.MyEntityMyGroup)
    .WithOne(group => group.MyEntity)
    .HasForeignKey<MyEntity>(e => e.Id);
```

The most important is the `HasForeignKey` generic type argument, since it tells EF Core which of the two entities is the *dependent*. And of course mapping the dependent PK property as FK.

For more info, see [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) topic of the official EF Core documentation.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't familiar with the concept of *Shared Primary Key Association*.